Condor job shadow exception
Whenever I try to run a condor job, I get this error:
007 (1240.000.000) 2024-06-19 16:32:47 Shadow exception!
Assertion ERROR on (result)
0  -  Run Bytes Sent By Job
0  -  Run Bytes Received By Job
Some people have said that changing certain file permissions fixes the shadow exception, but I did that and it hasn't worked. Line 8 should come after line 6, but when I run it that way it creates an error because it isn't running from a scram-based area.
this is the full .sh submission file:
#!/bin/bash
export VO_CMS_SW_DIR=/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch
source $VO_CMS_SW_DIR/cmsset_default.sh
export CMSSW_GIT_REFERENCE=/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/cmssw.git
export HOME=/home/ajl357/
cd $GEN_DIR_BASE
cd /cms/***/src
eval `scramv1 runtime -sh`
cmsenv
cd /cms/***/test
cmsRun AK4_improved.py inputTextFile='BG.txt' fileNum= $1

I've tried changing the permissions on all files included, I've tried changing the shebang in the .sh file as well as adding one to the AK4_improved.py python script, and I've tried many different configurations of the first few lines.
